# Analog signal change detection

Tags: analog, sample-and-hold

I'm attempting to monitor a voltage value for any change. I'd like to have a single digital output go high for some duration if the voltage changes at all with a minimum sensitivity of around 0.1 V. Preferably this would have some adjustability with the resolution/sensitivity at which this detects.

I've tried a sample and hold circuit comparing what the voltage was to what it is now but wasn't very happy with the results.

I also thought about running the analog signal through an ADC and comparing it with the output of another ADC. This had the added functionality of variable sensitivity but seems overcomplicated for a seemingly simple problem.

The biggest problem is I do not have a constant voltage to compare against. Everything can change depending on the set up of the circuit this is being used to monitor. Essentially, I need to constantly measure what the voltage is and then remeasure sometime later and test if they are different.

Comment: Classic case of "just use a microcontroller".

Comment: High-pass filter + comparator? Are there any requirements with regard to how fast (or slow) of a change must be detected?

Comment: A microcontroller makes sense, but @DaveTweed's idea is good too.  Essentially a differentiator to get the dv/dt and a comparator to put out a pulse when dv/dt exceeds a certain level.  You can adjust the time constant and reference level to the comparator to suit your needs.

Comment: So how long is "some time later"? milliseconds? seconds? hours?

Comment: @ElectronTrafficCop Unless you give more details; microcontroller can do it, as already said.

Comment: millisecond or quicker is more than adequate

Comment: And what is the range of the monitored voltages? 0..5V? Something else?

Comment: 12v currently but I could scale that down to 0-5 or really anything

Comment: To compare you can use a voltage reference IC, they provide a constant voltage.  But one thing is to compare against a constant voltage and another is to compare against previous values.

Comment: @ElectronTrafficCop I think the upshot of all these comments is that you can either go digital with an MCU or else go analog. If digital, you don't need to tell us any further detail because that will be your problem when writing the software and we don't care about your problems writing software. But if analog, then DaveTweed's thought is a way to go, though in this case you will need to specify/write more about details (you've been pretty obscure about them so far.)

Comment: @periblepsis - Hi, When you said: "*we don't care about your problems writing software*", the site's [on-topic list](/help/on-topic) *does* include "the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications". Of course I'm not trying to force *you* to care about that, we each have our areas of specialisation. However questions about writing firmware *are* on-topic here. || Purely programming-related questions *might* also be on-topic on Stack Overflow, but firmware programming can be on-topic both there and here. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson I was writing elliptically. To design something analog, all details are needed now. To design something with an MCU, the process can be broken into two parts. Not only has the decision between the two not yet been made by the questioner, but even if it were -- and an MCU were chosen -- it still would be putting the cart before the horse to worry about details writing the software. We'd be dealing with the MCU and surrounding circuitry, not software, at this point in the game. So *"we don't **currently** care about the software."* It's too far down the road from here in that case.

Comment: @SamGibson For now, in other words, we can sweep some details of the software coding of the embedded application under the rug and therefore don't currently require the same level of detail (some issues can be deferred, in other words, with an MCU involved) that would be otherwise needed for an analog design, today.

Comment: @periblepsis - Re: ""*we don't **currently** care about the software.*" It's too far down the road from here" Thanks for explaining your earlier comment, and I agree. It wasn't clear to me that this is what you originally meant. I'm glad this has been clarified.

Comment: @SamGibson I wrote it that way because I was thinking that for an analog design, full and complete specifications are necessary and required from the questioner. Nothing held back. Everything on the table. Even things that the questioner might not be aware of need to be asked and answered. That process is demanding and the questioner needs to be prepared for it and willing to deliver on it. But if an MCU is chosen then we don't have to care about quite so much and less is required because some details can be left to the coding process (which of course is a later problem of the questioner.)

Comment: Where is the problem with continous Adc reading and comparing with previous Adc value? If the difference is more than 0.1v start the action you want.

Comment: "if the voltage changes at all with a minimum sensitivity of around 0.1 V" Somehow @DaveTweed comment went unnoticed. I believe this question lacks clarity on time dimension. For example if the voltage changes by 0.1V in a span of a month, should it trigger the detection? This is important because the solutions are very different. If time does not matter you should look for ADC or analog comparator solution.  If it matters then you need a circuit based on analog integration.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution, by far, is a microcontroller with one ADC. Here's the kind of software you'd need to write (python-like pseudocode):

```
sensitivity = 0.1V
interval = 100ms
va = read_adc()
while True:
    vb = read_adc()
    if abs(vb - va) >= sensitivity:
        va = vb
        value_changed()
    wait(interval)
```

The only hardware required is a single microntroller (which could be as small as an 8 pin [ATtiny](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/attiny85)), and something to scale and limit the ADC's input.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty proposal:

[image]

First the input signal is lowpass filtered by R1/C1 and buffered by opamp X4. Feel free to add more active filtering using the opamp. The output of this filter is our "center threshold voltage" called "thr" on the schematic.

Then two adjustable current sources set the bounds for a [window comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_detector). For the upper bound I2 adds an offset voltage to "thr" through R2, and this is compared to the input signal. For the lower bound, I1 adds an offset voltage to the input signal, which gives the same result as substracting an offset from the threshold.

If any comparator triggers it means the current value of Vin is outside the window, which means it is more than the offset away from its filtered value. So it will detect change. The output is inverted, being open collector comparators, outputs can be wired together without using logic gates.

It will only detect voltage changes if they're faster than the low pass filter cutoff, which has to be chosen accordingly. So this is not the best circuit to detect very slow changes. However it is simple.

I'd recommend lowpass filtering the input too, to avoid triggering on noise/spikes.

To detect slow changes, the "just use a microcontroller" option should be a lot more convenient: acquire the signal at the beginning with the ADC with enough samples averaged to avoid noise, store the value, then keep running the ADC and compare the current value to the stored value. Keeping a constant value in RAM is essentially free, whereas keeping the voltage reasonably constant on a sample and hold capacitor for a long time is a whole can of worms. A microcontroller also allows smarter filtering options to avoid spurious triggering.

I did not use a differentiator because that takes into account the rate of change (that's the whole point of a differentiator) so it would be too sensitive to short high di/dt noise spikes. Also it would not be in the spirit of what you requested, which is closer to a window comparator.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add my two cents....

**(1) Complexity**

It is typicall - and for good reason - to aim for the simplest solution for a given problem. You can implement a "analog-solution" - be it discrete or with some Op-Amps - and be done. However, getting th ecomponent tolerances right, the circuit stable across the temp-range and so on requires engineering work to be done.

So i would suggest doing it digitally. As no "precise measurement" is required - only detection of changes - you can get away with a few resistors and a 8-pin micro-controller.

**(2) Ease of developement**

As implied previously: Analog-circuits work well in simulation. But not so much across the temperatur-, age-, and tolerance-range of the product/the components.
Engineering with this in mind takes time and effort.

**(3) Ease of manufacturing**

Assuming, that this is not a hobby project: The more complex your circuit gets, the more parts and board space you need. This translates into cost, concerns about reliability in the field, increased QA-requirements, and so on. So, the simple uC-Solution wins here as well.

**(4) Proposal**

I would like to suggest the following "circuit".

- Simple resistive pre-divider to Scale VIN to 0<->V_ADC
- TVS-Protection if required
- RC-Lowpass if required
- Feeding into a uC with 10Bit ADC (Or 12bit, or external ADC)

Running code like this:

```
void cfgAdc(void){
    /* Configure ADC for e.g. single measurement.
    * Can enable ISR here and use ISR to continously
    * trigger the comparison
    * Otherwise poll in while-loop
    * or have action in timer ISR
    */
}

uint16_t getAdcRaw(void){
    /* Platform specific */
    return (uint16_t)(value);
}

void cfgDigitalOutput(void){
    /* Configure as Output, set LOW/HIGH, rise-times, etc... */
}

void setDigitalOutput(void){
    /* set bit in IO register - Platform specific */
}

void clearDigitalOutput(void){
    /* clear bit in IO register - Platform specific */
}

void cfgAndEnTimerIsr(void){
    /* Configure a Timer ISR with 
    * the required interval and in 
    * "auto-reload" mode
    */
}

/* Stores the last measurement */
volatile uint16_t   adcRawLast = 0x0;
volatile uint16_t   adcRawCur = 0x0;
uint16_t            adcOffSet = 50U; //The sensitivity threshold
volatile uint8_t    initialSampleDone = 0x0;
ISR TimerIsr(ISR){
    /* Need to offset the ADC measurement to avoid math errors
    * due to wrapping in +/- ops...
    * Make sure, the ADC has a maximum of 15 Bits */
    adcRawCur = getAdcRaw();
    adcRawCur += adcOffSet;
    /* Check if initial sample was already done 
    * Otherwise output is always triggered on boot */
    if ( initialSampleDone == 0x0 ){
        /* First sample - so just set flag */
        initialSampleDone = 0x01;
        adcRawLast = adcRawCur;
    } 
    else if ( adcRawCur > adcRawLast + adcOffSet ||  adcRawCur < adcRawLast - adcOffSet ) {
        /* Detected change - store last measurement */
        setDigitalOutput();
        adcRawLast = adcRawCur;
    }
    else {
        /* Clear Output if no change present */
        clearDigitalOutput();
    }
}
```